# ERB partials to create static html with command line

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying make a very basic ERB to make an html file from multiple smaller html files. I read that I can use

```
<%= h(render "filename") %>
```

To add a the contents file called _filename.html.erb to the document. When I try to generate a file in command line using

```
erb test.html.erb > new-test.html
```

It get the error

```
test.html.erb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `render' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `eval'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:849:in `result'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb:831:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/erb:133:in `run'
    from /usr/bin/erb:154:in `<main>'
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to run it as a web app for "render" to work?

test.html.erb code for reference:

```
    <html lang="en">
     <body>

       <%= h(render "me") %>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `render` requires ActionView::PartialRenderer: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html.  In order to include that, you should write a ruby script which includes that package.  I'm not sure if that will fully solve your problem but should get you started.

Comment: Ok, I am very new to ruby, so how would I include that package?

Comment: I would take an hour and learn how to run Ruby scripts and how to include packages ("gems") within them.  Basically you're going to have a `run.rb` file that has `require` statements at the top, one of which will require `erb`.  Within that file you'll write the code necessary to render the erb in to a new file... or check this out: http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this script:

```
require 'erb'

def render(filename)
  ERB.new(File.read "#{filename}.html.erb").result(binding)
end

File.open('new-test.html', 'w') do |file|
  file.write render('test')
end
```

It will read your test.html.erb, interpolate the ruby code properly including the calls to our custom render (so no need for any external library to handle that), and output a new-test.html file. You can run it by:

```
ruby script_name.rb
```

Notice how we need to provide a binding object to ERB. It is what defines the context of evaluation of the interpolated ruby in the template. Here we are providing the binding of the script itself, that's why we have access to the render method inside the erb template.